# opengl shader problems with mrt

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, fbo

I have two textures with same size attached to one fbo, and I want to render another texture into one of the attached textures, and I want to render a blue shape of the figure of the input texture to the other fbo attached texture.

the (updated) vertex shader:

```
#version 330
in vec2 coord;
out vec2 f_coord;
void main() {
   gl_Position = vec4(coord, 0.0, 1.0);
   f_coord = (1.0+coord)/2.0;
}
```

the (updated) fragment shader:

```
#version 330
uniform sampler2D my_texture;
in vec2 f_coord;
out vec4 FragData[2];
void main() {
   if(texture(my_texture,f_coord).a == 0.0)
      discard;
   FragData[0]=texture(my_texture,f_coord);
   FragData[1]=vec4(0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

With this fragment shader everything works fine. The texture and the blue stamp of the texture contures are rendered properly.

Here is a screenshot:
http://s14.directupload.net/file/d/3487/kvkqdbl7_png.htm

But if I want to render the texture into gl_FragData[1] and the blue conture stamp into gl_FragData[0]

```
#version 330
uniform sampler2D my_texture;
in vec2 f_coord;
out vec4 FragData[2];
void main() {
   if(texture(my_texture,f_coord).a == 0.0)
      discard;
   FragData[0]=vec4(0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0);
   FragData[1]=texture(my_texture,f_coord);
}
```

than I get two totally blue textures. The strange thing is: Both target textures are totally blue, but I have set the glViewport just to a part of the texture.

Here a screenshot:
http://s1.directupload.net/file/d/3487/9loqibdc_png.htm

The fbo attachments have the half screen size

```
 glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH)/2, glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_BYTE, 0);
```

So I can render both textures to the screen for checking.

This is how I created the framebufferobject

```
 void init_fbo()
 {

     glGenTextures(1, &fbo.texture0);
     glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo.texture0);
     glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH)/2, glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_BYTE, 0);

     glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
     glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);


     glGenTextures(1, &fbo.texture1);
     glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo.texture1);
     glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH)/2, glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_BYTE, 0);

     glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
     glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

     glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);  

     glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo.fbo);

     glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo.fbo);

     glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                            fbo.texture0, 0);
     glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                            fbo.texture1, 0);

     glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
 }
```

I use those global struct variables

```
 struct
 {
     GLuint fbo;
     GLuint texture0;
     GLuint texture1;
 } fbo;

 struct
 {
     GLuint program;

     GLint uni_texture;
     GLint att_coord;
 } shader_fbo;

 struct
 {
     GLuint program;

     GLint uni_texture;
     GLint att_coord;
 } shader_screen;
```

And this is my render function

```
 void render()
 {   
     GLenum buffers[2];
     GLfloat vertices[] = { -1.0, -1.0,
                                -1.0,  1.0,
                                 1.0, -1.0,
                                 1.0,  1.0  };




     GLubyte indices[] = { 0, 1, 2,
                           1, 2, 3  };


     /*render to mrt fbo*/
     glUseProgram(shader_fbo.program);

     glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
     glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.texID);
     glUniform1i(shader_fbo.uni_texture, 0); 

     glEnableVertexAttribArray(shader_fbo.att_coord);
     glVertexAttribPointer(shader_fbo.att_coord,
                           2,
                           GL_FLOAT,
                           GL_FALSE,
                           0,
                           vertices);

     glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo.fbo);

     buffers[0] = GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0;
     buffers[1] = GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1;

     glDrawBuffers(2, buffers);

     glViewport(0, 0,
                texture.width, texture.height);

     glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
     glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.texID);
     glUniform1i(shader_fbo.uni_texture, 0);


     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

     glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indices);

     glDisableVertexAttribArray(shader_fbo.att_coord);
     glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
     glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);


     /*render both textures now to screen*/


     glUseProgram(shader_screen.program);

     glEnableVertexAttribArray(shader_screen.att_coord);
     glVertexAttribPointer(shader_screen.att_coord,
                           2,
                           GL_FLOAT,
                           GL_FALSE,
                           0,
                           vertices);



     /*render the first texture to the left side of the screen*/

     glViewport(0, 0,
                glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH)/2, glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT));


     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


     glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
     glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo.texture0);
     glUniform1i(shader_screen.uni_texture, 0); 

     glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indices);

     /*render the second texture to the right side of the screen*/

     glViewport(glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH)/2, 0,
                glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH)/2, glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT));


     glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
     glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo.texture1);
     glUniform1i(shader_screen.uni_texture, 0); 


     glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indices);


     glutSwapBuffers();

 }
```

Comment: your shaders are not valid GLSL for version 3.30.

Comment: @derhass I've deleted the version line from my shader sources. My graphics driver and card support opengl/glsl up to 4.30

 - "OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler"

Comment: well, are you using a core profile or compatibility?

Comment: @derhass I'm using the compatibility profile

Comment: @derhass When I use the core profile I get only a black screen, with both fragment shaders.

Comment: sure you do. your shaders aren't valid in core profile at all - that's why I was asking.

Comment: @derhass okay I've read this document http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL) So I replaced the attribute and the varying qualifiers

Comment: @derhass I've forgot to mention, the new shaders are at the end of my post.

Comment: @derhass after reading https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Predefined_Variables_By_Version I've changed my shader code again. Is it now correct?

Comment: One thing I see is that you still use `texture2D`. In newer GLSL, there is just the `texture()` function which will work with any sampler type - and leads to the next problem as you called your uniform `texture`. Do these shaders compile and links? Do you check for errors, read the compile/link logs?

Comment: @derhass I've changed the code. The nvidia compiler accepted these shaders. I've checked the shaders for errors with glGetShaderiv GL_COMPILE_STATUS and glGetProgramiv GL_LINK_STATUS, but everything compiled fine. Also the logs where empty.

Comment: @derhass The strange thing is, that everything works fine using the compatibility mode, but only if I don't swap the left XOR the right parts of those "FragData[]="-lines. It don't works with the core profile, even with the new shaders.